# Set Sharepoint drop down list equal to value entered in text box

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint list with several columns, one of which is a text box that is set to accept numbers.  I would like to auto populate a drop down box based on the number entered into that text box.

I am not very code-savvy, and so far all the answers I have found involve getting a number/value from a drop down box to insert into a text field, not the other way around.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with javascript or server side code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SelectedValue of the dropdown in code based on the textbox value. You need to add an event handler to the textbox (I believe KeyPressed event should be a good start)